# What are functions called that yield the same result when applied to one of their result values

Tags: terminology, functional-programming, mathematical-foundations

Suppose one of the following holds for all `x`, or all `y`, or all `z`:

```
f(f(x)) = f(x)
f(f(y)) = f(y)
f(f(f(z))) = f(f(z)) = f(z)
```

... how do you call such a function?

Answer (score 7):

A function satisfying that property is called [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Unary_operation).

Comment: Which is the answer if the function has the property for *all* inputs. The title seems to suggest the OP is looking at something else.

Comment: If the property existed only for a given set of inputs, I would most likely state it as "$f(x)$, $f(y)$, and $f(z)$ are *fixed points* of $f$" or, with a different wording, "$f(x)$, $f(y)$, and $f(z)$ are *fixed* by $f$". If $f$ is idempotent, then $f(x)$ is fixed by $f$ for all $x$.

Comment: I thought about "fixpoint", but those are $x$ with $f(x) = x$ -- not the same as $f(f(x)) = f(x)$. I don't know a term for "partially idempotent" functions. (Of course, if $f$ is some algorithm we iterate, e.g. a numerical one, then we'd say the final result -- when $f^{(n)}(x) = f^{(n-1)}(x)$ -- is a "fixpoint".)

Comment: As Raphael suggested, idempotent was not the answer I was looking for. Maybe there is no mathematical answer at all. Maybe it helps if I give a real-world example: consider jQuery. You can pass parameters to the jQuery function in lots of different ways. E.g. you can pass a selector, or an html string. Now, if you wrap whatever call with jQuery() again, you just get the same jQuery-Wrapping-Object returned back. This is useful, as it allows a developer not to care if an object has already been wrapped or not, a developer can just wrap it again to make sure to work with a jQuery object.

Comment: It would be completely accurate, if unusual, to say the jQuery function fixes jQuery-Wrapping-Objects or to say, when restricted to arrays (for example), jQuery is idempotent.